# Run a task after "tmp:clear"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a task that want to run after I run `rails tmp:clear`

```
namespace :myapp do
  task :clear do
    # do some stuff
  end
end
```

I've learned that I can do it by *enhancing* that task:

```
Rake::Task['tmp:clear'].enhance(['myapp:clear'])
```

The problem is that when my code is loaded, `tmp:clear` is undefined, so it fails:

```
$ rails tmp:clear
rails aborted!
 Don't know how to build task 'tmp:clear' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
 myapp/lib/tasks/clear.rake:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails tasks are loaded after local tasks. You need to `require 'rails/tasks'` before to circumvent that.

Complete solution:

```rb
require 'rails/tasks'

namespace :myapp do
  task :clear do
    puts "do some stuff"
  end
end

Rake::Task['tmp:clear'].enhance(['myapp:clear'])
```